# cocos2d taking screenshot in a part of layer?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I just want to take a screenshot only the middle part of the layer(it's an image) without menus positioned in the upper and lower part of the screen.is it possible to take a part of layer to an image?

```
//normal screenshots
-(UIImage *) screenshotWithNode:(CCNode*)node
{
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    CCRenderTexture* rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width
                                     height:winSize.height];
    [rtx begin];
    [node visit];
    [rtx end];

    return [rtx getUIImage];
}
```

Comment: put the part you want to take a screenshot of in a separate node or layer and only "visit" that node to grab it with the rendertexture

Comment: I tried your idea but couldn't work.because creating and displaying bunch of images with conditions on a other scene makes me to do lot of things..so I cropped the image after getting the screenshot.anyway thanks for the reply!